# Uber deeplink pickup location issues on iOS

Tags: ios, swift, uber-api, deeplink

I'm using Uber and Lyft deeplink in my app. The functionality is that when user click the "ride with uber" or "ride with lyft" button, it will open Uber or Lyft app, and send pickup and destination coordinates to Uber/Lyft, and Uber/Lyft app will handle the trip.

I used standard deeplink for Uber. Everything works fine when Uber is already open and running in the background. When Uber is not in the background, the pickup location turns to be the user's current location (which is wrong, because the user wants to specify a pickup location, not necessarily the current location). This issue does not happen in Lyft though.

This is my code:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var uberBtn: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var lyftBtn: UIButton!

    @IBAction func uberClicked(_ sender: Any) {
        if isInstalledOf(app: "uber") {
            open(scheme: "uber://?action=setPickup&client_id=7r6zjXf5e1p4nqYkX17d9R44estKs-na&product_id=a12ab23b-66f0-4028-9bb9-856dbcfdbbc7&pickup[formatted_address]=5874%20Newberry%20Street%2C%20Romulus%2C%20MI%2C%20USA&pickup[latitude]=42.265570&pickup[longitude]=-83.387391&dropoff[formatted_address]=15609%20Regina%20Avenue%2C%20Allen%20Park%2C%20MI%2C%20USA&dropoff[latitude]=42.253737&dropoff[longitude]=-83.211945")
        } else {
            open(scheme: "https://m.uber.com/ul/")
        }
    }

    @IBAction func lyftClicked(_ sender: Any) {
        if isInstalledOf(app: "lyft") {
            open(scheme: "lyft://ridetype?id=lyft&pickup[latitude]=42.265570&pickup[longitude]=-83.387391&destination[latitude]=42.253737&destination[longitude]=-83.211945")
        } else {
            open(scheme: "https://www.lyft.com/signup/SDKSIGNUP?clientId=IcEuyAmFO7Gp&sdkName=iOS_direct")
        }
    }

    // check if the app is installed
    func isInstalledOf(app: String) -> Bool {
        return UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(URL(string: "\(app)://")!)
    }

    func open(scheme: String) {
        if let url = URL(string: scheme) {
            if #available(iOS 10, *) {
                UIApplication.shared.open(url, options: [:], completionHandler: nil)
            } else {
                UIApplication.shared.openURL(url)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Try using the user SDK https://github.com/uber/rides-ios-sdk, rather than making your own implementations. It would be easy to debug.... If not, rather than using deep links, use universal deep links...

Comment: I tried using UberRides SDK and universal deeplink, neither of them could solve this problem :( Everything works just fine except the pickup location

Comment: I suppose this was created by you... https://github.com/uber/rides-ios-sdk/issues/249... It definitely looks like a bug with the Uber App... I would say hang in there until and unless somebody from Uber responds..

Comment: Thanks for the link. It's not created by me, but I have the exact same problem as his.

Comment: Keep following the issue.. Someone will definitely respond to it, if its widespread..

Answer (score 1):

Use Uber SDK and pass required parameters for deeplink. To resolve pickup location issue you need to pass pickup name and pickup address

```
        let pickupLocation          = CLLocation(latitude: <pickup latitude>, longitude: <pickup longitude>)
        let dropoffLocation         = CLLocation(latitude: <destination latitude>, longitude: <destination longitude>)
        let builder                 = RideParametersBuilder()
        builder.pickupLocation      = pickupLocation
        builder.pickupNickname      = <pickup nickname>
        builder.pickupAddress       = <pickup address>
        builder.dropoffLocation     = dropoffLocation
        builder.dropoffNickname     = <dropof nickname>
        builder.dropoffAddress      = <dropof address>
        builder.productID           = productId
        let deeplink                = RequestDeeplink(rideParameters: builder.build(), fallbackType: .appStore)
        deeplink.execute()
```

Comment: Use Uber SDK and pass required parameters for deeplink. To resolve pickup location issue you need to pass pickup name and pickup address.

Answer (score 0):

I got confirmation(10/29/2018) from Uber that this issue is internal. This issue happens when Uber is not open, and Android does not has this issue. They are working on fixing this issue currently but unfortunately no ETA for now. Here is the message from Uber:

> Thanks for the report. I see the issue on Github:
>   https://github.com/uber/rides-ios-sdk/issues/249 …  I can confirm the
>   problem. It works correctly on Android but does not work correctly on
>   IOS when the app is not open. Unfortunately no ETA but I will try and
>   route this correctly internally.

Comment: Acknowledgment of the issue on Github from an engineer who will be working on it: https://github.com/uber/rides-ios-sdk/issues/249  "Thanks for reporting this issue. We are currently looking into it and will provide an update soon."